# Is there an equivalent of Google Hangouts for calls to England?

Tags: web-apps, voip

> [ [Source :](https://support.google.com/hangouts/answer/3187125?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) ] Almost all calls to the U.S. and Canada are free from all countries where Hangouts calling is available.

What allows free calls to England, from either a computer or an Android phone?

Comment: Do you want to call physical phone numbers? Or is it OK to require your friends to install a special app?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul The goal is physical phone numbers; no, I cannot require the recipients to install any applications.

Comment: Are these calls international? If so, that's going to be quite close to impossible.

Comment: @tuskiomi The caller can be in the UK, or in North America; so in that sense it is international. But the recipient phone number is always one in England.

Answer (score -1):

You could check in with Microsoft Skype - they're always having some awesome promotion packages with free calls around the world.
[skype unlimited world calling](https://www.skype.com/en/offers/unlimited-world-calling/)

Comment: There is no such promotion right now, it seems. More generally, a permanent solution would be preferable.